# Is regenerating enterprise iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile will crash installed app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an enterprise iOS app which installed over more than 2000 devices and working fine.

Recently we are facing and issue in installing the app, we got this message: “Unable to download application.  could not be installed at this time”.

After search, I am confident now that the problem is Invalid iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile.

My questions:

1. If I regenerate the iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile, dose this action will affect on the app that already installed on the users devices?
2. Do I have to rebuild my app with the new Distribution Provisioning Profile and replace the old IPA ?

Regards

Comment: Is this on store or a add-hock release ?

Comment: It is enterprise app on private store

Comment: In that case expired date matters , in apple Appstore it does not. So in your case it will not effect the existing applications. They will stay expired and unable to use. And yes you will have distribute with the regenerated provisioning profile.

Comment: What do you mean by "They will stay expired and unable to use" ? The already installed app? or the old IPA ? 

And is there a reference from Apple about this?

Comment: In our use case we distribute our inhouse app distributions with a addhock profile and when it expires we have to put a new ipa with updated profile. In your case I guess if you have  the same kind of profile, your old ipa and installed apps will not be able to use. Only the new build can help. Not sure about the Apple referent I was speaking with experience of such cases. If you google it up, I am pretty sure you could find some references.